# What does the notation $u_x^{(j)}$ mean, when dealing with systems of equations?

Tags: notation, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

When dealing with linear and semi-linear systems of equations, I begin seeing the notation
$$
u_x^{(j)}
$$

Obviously the $u_x$ part of this simply denotes the partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$, but what does the ${}^{(j)}$ part of this notation mean?

Does it denote that we are dealing with the $j$th partial derivative of $u_x$? Or does it mean $(u_x)^j$? Or something else?

For example, you can see this notation used in the below system of equations:

[image: notation]

Comment: My guess is $$u_x^{(j)} = \frac{\partial^j u}{\partial x^j}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's a notation for **higher derivatives**.

From [Notation for differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation):

Higher derivatives are indicated using additional prime marks, as in $f''(x)$ for the second derivative and $f'''(x)$ for the third derivative. The use of repeated prime marks eventually becomes unwieldy. Other authors use Arabic numerals in parentheses, as in:
$$f^{(4)}(x),f^{(5)}(x),f^{(6)}(x)...$$
This notation also makes it possible to describe the n-th derivative, like:
$$f^{(n)}(x)$$